# compiling openss7

Tags: compilation

i got an error while compiling openss7.

Do you know what happen ? 
Thanks....

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I. -I. -I. -DLFS=1 -imacros ./config.h -imacros ./include/sys/config.h -I. -I./include -I./include -nostdinc -iwithprefix include -DLINUX -D__KERNEL__ -I/usr/src/linux-headers-lbm-2.6.28-11-generic -I/lib/modules/2.6.28-11-generic/build/include -Iinclude2 -I/lib/modules/2.6.28-11-generic/build/include -I/lib/modules/2.6.28-11-generic/build/arch/x86/include -include /lib/modules/2.6.28-11-generic/build/include/linux/autoconf.h -Iubuntu/include -I/lib/modules/2.6.28-11-generic/build/ubuntu/include -I/lib/modules/2.6.28-11-generic/build/arch/x86/include/asm/mach-default '-DKBUILD_STR(s)=#s' '-DKBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR('`echo libLfS_specfs_a-specfs.o | sed -e 's,lib.*_a-,,;s,\.o,,;s,-,_,g'`')' -DMODULE  -D__NO_VERSION__ -DEXPORT_SYMTAB  -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -O2 -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i586 -mtune=generic -Wa,-mtune=generic32 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -fno-stack-protector -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fwrapv -ffreestanding  -c -o libLfS_specfs_a-specfs.o `test -f 'src/kernel/specfs.c' || echo './'`src/kernel/specfs.c
In file included from src/kernel/specfs.c:123:
src/kernel/strspecfs.c: In function ‘specfs_init_cache’:
src/kernel/strspecfs.c:1406: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘kmem_cache_create’ from incompatible pointer type
src/kernel/strspecfs.c:1406: error: too many arguments to function ‘kmem_cache_create’
In file included from src/kernel/specfs.c:126:
src/kernel/strlookup.c: In function ‘cdev_lookup’:
src/kernel/strlookup.c:508: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
src/kernel/strlookup.c:514: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
src/kernel/strlookup.c:521: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
src/kernel/strlookup.c: In function ‘cdrv_lookup’:
src/kernel/strlookup.c:562: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
src/kernel/strlookup.c: In function ‘fmod_lookup’:
src/kernel/strlookup.c:604: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
src/kernel/strlookup.c: In function ‘cdev_search’:
src/kernel/strlookup.c:709: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
src/kernel/strlookup.c:716: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
src/kernel/strlookup.c: In function ‘fmod_search’:
src/kernel/strlookup.c:768: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
src/kernel/strlookup.c: In function ‘cmin_search’:
src/kernel/strlookup.c:823: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
src/kernel/strlookup.c:830: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
src/kernel/strlookup.c:840: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
src/kernel/strlookup.c:848: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
In file included from src/kernel/specfs.c:129:
src/kernel/strattach.c: In function ‘check_mnt’:
src/kernel/strattach.c:131: error: ‘struct vfsmount’ has no member named ‘mnt_namespace’
src/kernel/strattach.c:131: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘namespace’
src/kernel/strattach.c: In function ‘do_fattach’:
src/kernel/strattach.c:200: error: ‘struct nameidata’ has no member named ‘dentry’
src/kernel/strattach.c:200: error: ‘struct nameidata’ has no member named ‘mnt’
src/kernel/strattach.c:200: error: ‘struct nameidata’ has no member named ‘dentry’
src/kernel/strattach.c:203: error: ‘struct nameidata’ has no member named ‘mnt’
src/kernel/strattach.c:208: error: ‘struct nameidata’ has no member named ‘mnt’
src/kernel/strattach.c:208: error: ‘struct nameidata’ has no member named ‘mnt’
src/kernel/strattach.c:208: error: ‘struct nameidata’ has no member named ‘dentry’
src/kernel/strattach.c:226: error: implicit declaration of function ‘path_release’
src/kernel/strattach.c: In function ‘do_fdetach’:
src/kernel/strattach.c:253: error: ‘struct nameidata’ has no member named ‘dentry’
src/kernel/strattach.c:253: error: ‘struct nameidata’ has no member named ‘mnt’
src/kernel/strattach.c:255: error: ‘struct nameidata’ has no member named ‘mnt’
src/kernel/strattach.c:257: error: ‘struct nameidata’ has no member named ‘dentry’
src/kernel/strattach.c:262: error: ‘struct nameidata’ has no member named ‘mnt’
src/kernel/strattach.c:265: error: ‘struct nameidata’ has no member named ‘mnt’
In file included from src/kernel/specfs.c:132:
src/kernel/strpipe.c: In function ‘do_spipe’:
src/kernel/strpipe.c:372: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
make[4]: *** [libLfS_specfs_a-specfs.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/deddihp/dev/source/openss7-0.9.2.G/streams-0.9.2.4'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/deddihp/dev/source/openss7-0.9.2.G/streams-0.9.2.4'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/deddihp/dev/source/openss7-0.9.2.G/streams-0.9.2.4'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/deddihp/dev/source/openss7-0.9.2.G'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: what was your kernel and which kernel did you donwgrade to?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the conclusion,

it is because of my kernel is newer, so i have to downgrade it.